# Find integer solutions to x being an element in an equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

We began the topic of Cryptography in our Discrete Math class and for our first homework assignment, we were given the following problem:

Find all integer solutions to x $\equiv$ 3 (mod 6)

How would you solve this? Unfortunately the textbook doesn't contain this specific problem and I've been unable to find information on this.

Comment: $6k + 3$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is there a specific name for that theory/proof?

Comment: It is just the definition of mod. $x=3\bmod 6$ means that $x$ is a multiple of 6 plus 3.

Comment: @DemCodeLines Just use the (defining) fact that $a \equiv b \pmod n$ iff $n \mid (b - a)$.

Comment: @AnotherTest If you are able to detail step by step on solving that, I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $a \equiv b \mod{n}$ if $a - b = kn$ for some integer $k$.  Hence, $x \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$ means $x - 3 = 6k$, for some integer $k$.  Solving for $x$ yields $x = 6k + 3$ for some integer $k$.  Thus, the solution set of the congruence is $S = \{6k + 3 \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.